# SpringBootTest - H2 - Function "SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH" not found

Tags: spring-boot, h2, spring-boot-test, java-17

I have a SpringBoot application that uses SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH Oracle function in one of its queries, now I want to run some tests to prove these queries. I've tried to use H2 memory database with Oracle mode but it didn't work.

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = CSM_SECURITY
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer = allow
spring.jpa.open-in-view = false
spring.sql.init.platform = oracle
spring.sql.init.mode = embedded
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;Mode=Oracle
```

Is there any way to use SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH function with H2 memory database?